# How to declare or create a scheduled GCP function using serverless framework?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, triggers, google-cloud-functions, serverless-framework, schedule

I'm using GCP and serverless framework. And wish to create a scheduled function. For AWS lambdas i can add to the .yml:

```
functions:
  crawl:
    handler: crawl
    events:
      - schedule: rate(2 hours)
      - schedule: cron(0 12 * * ? *)
```

Seems like no such option for GCP - correct me if i'm wrong.
What is the simplest way to implement it in CGP?

Comment: Google Cloud Scheduler: https://rominirani.com/google-cloud-functions-tutorial-using-the-cloud-scheduler-to-trigger-your-functions-756160a95c43

Comment: @john-hanley -- your comment is the answer ;-)

Comment: A one-package solution is to use [Firebase functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) you are limited to NodeJS but it wrap your scheduling in the deployment step. The same underlying infrastructure is used for the processing: Cloud Function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the responses, this is the complete solution as i see it including yaml:

In serverless.yml:

```
functions:
  oneMinute:
    handler: oneMinuteHandler
    events:
      - event:
          eventType: providers/cloud.pubsub/eventTypes/topic.publish
          resource: 'projects/${self:provider.project, ""}/topics/one-minute-topic'
```

This will also create the topic when running `serverless deploy`

Now all that is left is to create a scheduler:

GCP -> Cloud Scheduler -> Create Job

Target: Pub/Sub

Topic:  one-minute-topic

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud's recommended solution for scheduling services such as Cloud Functions is Cloud Scheduler.

Cloud Scheduler is a fully managed service with enterprise-reliability and supports the popular Unix/Linux cron format.

[Cloud Scheduler product information](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler)

[Google Cloud Functions Tutorial: Using the Cloud Scheduler to trigger your functions](https://rominirani.com/google-cloud-functions-tutorial-using-the-cloud-scheduler-to-trigger-your-functions-756160a95c43)

[Cloud Scheduler Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/quickstart/)